# bot responds to specific channel discord.js

Tags: command, discord, discord.js, bots, helper

How do I get a bot to respond only to a specific channel where I write a command

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content.startsWith("hey")) {
        message.channel.send('hello');
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is to check message.channel.name against the name of the authorized channel or list of channels. For example `if (message.channel.name === "BotLounge")`. For other information available about the channel please see https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel

Answer (score 0):

You can use `message.channel.id` because the channel has a unique id, or you can check with `message.channel.name` but this is less unique, and you can have troubles with it.

Sou you can do something like:

```
const myChannelId = '0123456789'

client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.channel.id === myChannelId) return;
    if(message.content.startsWith("hey")) {
        message.channel.send('hello');
    } 
});
```