# How to make the Bot only work in specific channels?

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, chatbot

I opened 2 channels, profanity is allowed in 1 channel, the other will be prohibited, but when the bot deletes the messages in both channels when swearing in 2 channels, how can I do this in 1 channel, for example, there are chat1 and chat2, the bot can only delete the messages in chat1.

---

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes('.ad')){
        message.delete()
        message.reply("orosbu evladı ananı sikmeden ticketden kullan komutu chata birdaha yazarsan banlancan")
    }
}
)
```

---

```
I opened 2 channels, profanity is allowed in 1 channel, the other will be prohibited, but when the bot deletes the messages in both channels when swearing in 2 channels, how can I do this in 1 channel, for example, there are chat1 and chat2, the bot can only delete the messages in chat1.


--------


client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes('.ad')){
        message.delete()
        message.reply("orosbu evladı ananı sikmeden ticketden kullan komutu chata birdaha yazarsan banlancan")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65439745/bot-responds-to-specific-channel-discord-js) you can check the message `channel id` against the `id` of the channel that you want the bot to operate on.

The general code would be:

```
const disallowProfanityChannelID= '0123456789'

client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.channel.id === disallowProfanityChannelID) {
       block_profanity();
    }
});
```

For your specific use case:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.channel.id === disallowProfanityChannelID) {
        if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes('.ad')){
            message.delete()
            message.reply("orosbu evladı ananı sikmeden ticketden kullan komutu chata birdaha yazarsan banlancan")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where do i write it from here can you edit and post this code idyi i will write it

Comment: client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes('.ad')){
        message.delete()
        message.reply("orosbu evladı ananı sikmeden ticketden kullan komutu chata birdaha yazarsan banlancan")
    }
}
)